# if subdirectory doesnt exist run error page

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I have a problem with routing in Play Framework 2.0.2. When I type into browser subdirectory which doesnt exist (etc. localhost/directory/) I get page:

```
Action not found For request 'GET /directory/'.
```

What do I need add into `routes` file if I want on every subdirectory which doesn't exist run etc. `controllers.Application.show(page = "error")`?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaGlobal) for custom  `onHandlerNotFound()` and render custom content instead of redirecting it to other resource, ie:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {      
    @Override
    public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
       return notFound(views.html.error.render("Your page was not found"));
    }
}
```

(create new view as well: `app/views/error.scala.html` and stylize it as you wish)